# Strange HDD Issue

Tags: mount, ssh, hard-drive, nautilus, 20.04

So I am having a really strange issue with a 2nd HDD on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have a personal nextcloud server with two hard drives - a main drive which has all my files as well as Ubuntu files, and a second drive. I run a cron job every night which uses rsync to create a mirror image of my files as a backup.

What is weird is after a few days, my cron job stops working because it can't see the backup drive. When I SSH to /media/ nothing is there. I even went into disk management and set the backup drive to never sleep and APM to 255. The drive is mounted as well.

The only way I have found to fix this is to physically access the server, and open the drive's location in nautilus. After I do this, the rsync command works as intended, and I can then SSH in and the files are available at /media//mybackup

This seems to fix the issue for a while, but after a reboot I can no longer access the drive via SSH, until I actually go into nautilus, navigate to my backup folder, and then it works again.

Any ideas on what could be causing this type of behavior? Thanks!

Comment: Is the second drive an external drive?   I've had external drives power-save before (after period(s) of inactivity) making them a pain to use in home-serving roles. In my case I didn't find proper fix, just created a background job that queried drive and prevented it from entering it's power-save mode (by-passing my issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but after a reboot I can no longer access the drive via SSH, until I actually go into nautilus, navigate to my backup folder, and then it works again.

You need to mount the storage device with an entry in /etc/fstab. That way it is automatically mounted when you reboot the machine.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!!